# Count the number of items in a certain status for a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to count the number of orders in a given status for given date.  In example data, the order status is a timeline that is only updated when the order moves on to the next status.

Sample Data:

```
Order_ID    Status     Status_Date
--------    ------     -----------------------
56845       NEW        2012-09-11 11:52:20.000
56845       SENT       2012-09-12 00:22:13.000
56845       ACK        2012-09-17 08:14:33.000
56845       FILL       2012-09-20 14:32:00.000
36968       NEW        2012-09-08 11:52:20.000
36968       SENT       2012-09-15 00:22:13.000
36968       ACK        2012-09-22 08:14:33.000
48258       NEW        2012-09-14 11:52:20.000
48258       SENT       2012-09-20 00:22:13.000
48258       ACK        2012-09-22 08:14:33.000
48258       FILL       2012-09-28 23:22:46.000
48258       SHIP       2012-09-29 18:54:22.000
```

My difficulty is I need to select the last row that was entered for each order that is less than a specific date and count it if it is in a certain status.

So if I'm using the status = 'SENT' and a date of 9/12/2018 at midnight, I want to return order-id 56845 and 36968.  If I'm using a status = 'SENT' and a date of 9/21/2018 at midnight, I want to return order-id 36968 and 48258 because order-id 56845 is in 'FILL' status and no longer in 'SENT'.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Basically I somehow need the last status (top 1) for each order-id where the status date is < than a given date.  Its selecting the top 1 for each order-id that is given me trouble

Answer (score 0):

`select count(*) from(select order_id,status from table group by order_id having max(status_date) <= '2012-09-16' or max(status_date) = '2012-09-21' and status ='SENT' )`
This is what you are looking for this means if at max status date for each individual order if the items status doesnt change or it is sent until max date less than your date you get the correct result.

Comment: This is close but it is returning all of the orders that went through sent status.  I just need the ones that were in sent status as of that date.  So for a date of 9/12/2012 it should return 2 (Order-ID 56845 and 36968) and for a date of 9/21/2012 it still should return 2 (Order-ID 36968 and 48258)

Answer (score -1):

You can use below one

```
select count(1) from table_name where status='NEW' group by Status_Date
```

or you can use this one to get count for all status in all  dates

```
select count(1) as count,Status,left(Status_Date,10) as Status_Date   from table_name 
group by Status,left(Status_Date,10)
```

Comment: I failed to mention the dates are really a time line that only get updated when the order switches to a  new status. So if the date is midnight on 9/20/2018, I only have 2 orders in SENT status as the first order, has moved onto FILL status

Comment: @mlwrig2 that is an important requirement. Please edit that into your question so that it will be seen

Comment: Thanks, can't tell I'ma newbie can you :)